# Why does required ng -message show up even when updateOn is set to blur?

Tags: angularjs

```
<label>Integer</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="uForm.int" required name="int" 
       int-validator ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">

<div ng-messages="myForm.int.$error">
 <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
 <div ng-message="uIntVal">This is Invalid</div>
</div>
```

For the above markup, the `required` message always shows up when the view is initialized.

Angular 1.4

Comment: I would think updateOn [event] affects model values (uForm.int) not form validity check, what you need is to also check form not pristine, aka dirty ng-if='formName.inputName.$dirty'

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ng-if into the initial div,

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.int.$error" ng-if="myForm.int.$dirty">
 <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
 <div ng-message="uIntVal">This is Invalid</div>
</div>
```

see this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLKwcHX28YjdfWIHZxA9?p=preview).

I did try to add an `AND (&&)` operator into the expression, but this doesn't seem to work, so I found [this link](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2015/1/27/angularjs-forms-best-practices), and this works.

Below **didn't work** for me...

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.int.$error && myForm.int.$dirty">
 <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
 <div ng-message="uIntVal">This is Invalid</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup! Even i tried && and it did not work. Your solution works and I have tried it before posting this question here. I wanna know why doesn't it work when ng-model-options is set?